# Difficulty parsing text file Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, parsing

Using Python 2.7, I want to take a file as input, remove some charachters from it, and write that to another file.
I'm not entirely succeeding with the below code:

```
print 'processing .ujc file for transmit'
infile, outfile = open('app_code.ujc','r'), open('app_code_transmit.ujc','w')
data = infile.read()
data = data.replace("#include <avr/pgmspace.h> const unsigned char uj_code[] PROGMEM = {", "")
data = data.replace("0x", "")
data = data.replace(", ", "")
data = data.replace("};", "")
outfile.write(data)
```

The input file (example) is:

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

const unsigned char uj_code[] PROGMEM = {

    0x00, 0x03, 0xB1, 0x4B, 0xEC, 0x00, 0x1D, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x21, 0x00, 0x02, 0x6A, 0x00, 0x02, 
    0x6A, 0x00, 0x02, 0xE3, 0x3F, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x00, 0x02, 0x2C, 0x00, 0x01, 0x3B, 0x00, 0x02, 0x36, 0x00, 0x00
};
```

And this should become (the etc is a continuation of the above and not actually present):

```
0003B14BEC001D001E002100026A00(...etc...)02360000
```

What I get with the above code is:

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

const unsigned char uj_code[] PROGMEM = {

    0003B14BEC001D001E002100026A00(...etc...)
    02360000
```

In other words, I want to remove all character, empty lines, and 0x and stuff except the actual bytes in a single continuous line but I'm tripping a little bit on the nuances, I'm expecting. Any help?

Comment: You try to replace two different lines with one statement. There's some '\n' (or '\r\n') in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MKesper is right. When you read the file, there are \n or \r\n (line separators) depending on your OS. Looking at the expected output, I feel the better way would be to extract the data you need rather than delete the unwanted data. I would take some help from regular expression and here is my attempt:

```
import re
print 'processing .ujc file for transmit'
infile, outfile = open('app_code.ujc','r'), open('app_code_transmit.ujc','w')
data = infile.read()
# Expect 0003B14BEC001D001E002100026A00026A0002E33F001F00022C00013B0002360000 to be the output
outfile.write(''.join(re.findall('0x([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])', data)))
```

Update 1: This is based on assumption that you do not have any other 0x. Else we need to update our regular expression

Comment: This is a better approach than mine, thanks.
One small caveat: in the sixth line, it is not 'str' but 'data'. Alternatively, rename 'data' to 'str'.

Answer (score 0):

Your input file is split on multiple lines and you are after a single line output.

You simply need to strip any newline characters before writing:

```
data.strip("\n")
```

Comment: You are right, forgot the invisible characters. Thanks.